# what is the hour hand rotation angle per second on a wall clock?

Tags: javascript, math, rotation

Am writing a javascript function to rotate the hour hand per second .

For example:

1 second = 6 deg ("rotation angle")

1 minute = 6 / 60 = 0.1 deg ("rotation angle per second")

**Question**

1 hour = ???? = ???? deg ("rotation angle per second")

***My Initial guess***

my guess was : since 1 hour = 3600 seconds
then 1 hour = 6 / 3600 = 0.001666667 deg ("rotation angle per second")
But this was wrong when i implemented it in my clock application.
It made the hour hand move only by 1 / 5 hours per hour instead of 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

12 hours : 360 degs
1 hour   : 30 degs
60 mins  : 30 degs
1 min    : 0.5 degs
60 s     : 0.5 degs
1 s      : 0.00833333333... degs

If my math is right, that's your answer

Comment: Sorry @Thomas, may be you got me wrong.  my **basic question** is: if the second hand moves 6 deg per second , how many degrees per second will the hour hand on a clock move ? An explanation will be very well appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation to your answer ?

Comment: Ah, misunderstood, but the answer should still apply. 6 deg/s on the seconds hand is 360 deg/min, which is real time.  
What I did is that the hours hand moves 360 degrees in 12 hours, which means that it moves 30 degrees in 1 hour, or half a degree a minute. I keep this going, and all the ratios in my answer are constant; they are all equal to "12 hours : 360 degs", with both sides being divided by a scalar. In all lines, the value on the left is the time passing, and the right is the rotation performed in that time. The rotation velocity of the hours hand is 0.0083333 deg/s.

Comment: Ahhhh  @Thomas, Now i feel so much better. Now you deserve the _"Accepted Answer"_ Bonus. At first i was just seeing a list of _equality statements_.  Keep up the good work!!

Answer (score 1):

The hour hand rotates `360 degrees` in twelve hours; its angular velocity is `360 degrees/12 hours = 30 degrees/hour`.

There are `3600 seconds` in an hour.

Therefore, the angular velocity of the hour hand is

```
(30 degrees/hour)*(1 hour/3600 seconds) = 0.0083333333 degree/second
```

It's a simple matter of units.

Comment: Ok @duffymo, Let's get this right. am making a `transform: rotate(__ deg)` per second on the _second_, _minute_ and _hour_ hand of a clock application. i have set my second hand to rotate `6 deg per second interval` ...which according to my calculation the _minute hand_ will move `6 deg / 60` = 0.1 deg and its working fine. But my **challenge** is figuring out the rotation for the _hour hand_ per second interval. I hope this makes it more clear

Comment: I think it's clear.  The two answers you have agree.  The calculation is for the hour hand.

Comment: Well @duffymo, I didn't initially agree with your answer because it was suggesting that the _hour hand_ rotates by `0.1 deg` _per second interval_.  .. After editing your answer , i believe it now makes more sense.  I will upvote your answer after trying it out.. Thank you for your input

Comment: Silly error by me.  What's there now is correct.  You should accept Thomas Jager's answer - he had it first.

Comment: may be am missing something.  Isn't the answer `0.00833333333` instead of `0.083333333` ? Your answer states `0.083333333`

Comment: Multiplication sign is correct.  Missed a zero; corrected now.  The key thing is explanation.